# Connect to z/OS Mainframe with SFTP

Tags: sftp, zos, ebcdic

We have a IBM Host System Z sitting in our cellar. Now the issue is that i have no clue about Mainframes!!! (It's not USS btw.)

The Problem: How can i transfer a file from the host system to a windows machine.

Usually on UNIX systems i would just install and ssh daemon and connect to it via. a program called winscp. After that transfer the file in binary so that it does not convert something (Ultraedit and other Editors can handle this).

With the host system it seems to be a bit difficult as the original format from IBM is EBCDIC and i have no idea if there is a state of the art SFTP server program for the host. Could anybody be so kind and enlighten me? From my current expirience with IT there must be a state of the art sftp connection to that system? I appreciate any help/hints/solutions.

Thank you,
O.S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mainframe "sitting in [your] cellar" is running z/OS then it has Unix System Services installed.  You can't have z/OS without it.

There is an [SFTP package](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/ported/openssh/) available (for free) for z/OS.

You can test to see about Unix System Services by firing up a 3270 emulator going to ISPF option 3.17, putting a forward slash (`/`) in the `Pathname` field and pressing the mainframe Enter key.  Another way would be to key `OMVS` at a TSO `READY` prompt, which will start up a 3270-based Unix shell.

It is possible that USS is simply not available to *you*; if you're running any supported release of z/OS then USS is *present*.  There could be concerns about supporting something outside a particular group,

Comment: Thanks for your response, our engineers claim that there is no USS installed. What can i do to prove that there is USS installed? (and sorry for this easy question but i have really 0 knowledge about mainframes)

Comment: It seems that your sentence was correct "USS is simply not available to you" thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Or, depending on what OS you have running on your System z, it's possible you don't have z/OS.  You could have z/VM, you could have zLinux, you could have TPF.  However, if you're running zLinux, you have linux, which has sftp installed, and which uses ASCII, not EBCDIC.

As cschneid says, however, if you have z/OS, you have USS.  TCP/IP, among other things, won't run without it.  Also note that z/OS TCP/IP has an FTP server, so you can connect that way if the FTP server is set up.  If security is an issue, FTPS is supported, although it's painful to set up.  With the native FTP server, you can convert from EBCDIC to ASCII when you're doing the transfer.  There's also an NFS server available.  And SMB as well, I believe.

And there's an FTP client available as well, so you could FTP from z/OS to your system, if you wanted to.

Maybe a better thing to do would explain what you're trying to do with the data, and what the data is, in general.  You can edit files directly on the mainframe, using either TSO, ISPF, or OMVS editors.  There are a lot of data types that the mainframe supports that you're not going to be able to handle on a non-z system unless you go through an export process.  I'm not really clear on whether you want to convert the file to ASCII when you transfer it or not.

Answer (score 1):

While the others are correct that all recent releases of z/OS have USS built-in, there's quite a bit of setup work that needs to be done in order for individual users to have access to USS capabilities like SFTP. Out of the box, you get USS "minimal mode" that just has enough of USS to support the TCP/IP stack and so forth. USS "full function mode" requires setup:

- HFS filesystems need to be allocated
- Your security package needs to be manage UIDs/GIDs for your users
- etc etc etc

Still, with these details and with nothing more than the software you're entitled to as part of your z/OS license, you can certainly run SFTP and all the other UNIX style network services you're used to.

A good place to start is the UNIX Services Planning guide: http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/bpxzb2c0.pdf